# case insensitive query for key_name

Tags: python, google-app-engine, key, case-insensitive

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to make case insensitive filter queries with Google App Engine?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3289781/how-to-make-case-insensitive-filter-queries-with-google-app-engine)

Can a GAE datastore be queried case insensitively for a key_name? Maybe query is not the right term. I really want to do a `get_by_key_name()` so the user does not have to have the correct case, but does have the correct text characters.

Comment: Yes, I guess it is a duplicate (that I was not able to find when I searched before posting). Thanks.

Comment: Actually, this is not a duplicate - though the answer is the same - the other post refers to queries, not get operations.