# GAE: User By Name / Regex Expressions

Tags: python, regex, google-app-engine, web-applications, web

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to make case insensitive filter queries with Google App Engine?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3289781/how-to-make-case-insensitive-filter-queries-with-google-app-engine)

Currently on my web app,

If I type in www.website.com/Rohit , it takes me to my desired profile page.

But if I type in www.website.com/rohit , it does not take me there, and it gets sent to the 404 error.

Basically, my username is stored as: Rohit

And any given user's profile page is supposed to be: www.website.com/username

But I want the website to not care about capitals.

**UPDATE**

I now know, thanks to Martijn that my regex expression is ok. This is the code, I use to check Google App Engine to see if a username already exists or not:

```
u = User.all().filter('username =', username).get()
```

^How do I make this capitals-friendly (capital letters don't make a difference?)

Comment: That regular expression is already matching lower *and* uppercase letters. The regular expression is *not* your problem.

Comment: Ok thanks, originally this was a different question though, I guess I didn't check again like I did initially if the question was already on StackOverflow - initially about regex expressions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use `filter('username =', username.lower())` to convert to lowercase beforehand.

and you need to convert your database, changing all user names to lowercase as well:

```
users = User.all().fetch(1000000)
for user in users :
    if user.username != user.username.lower() :
        user.username = user.username.lower()
        user.put()  # save back to db only if changed
```

you may run this from interactive console, using `fetch(offset,count)` to adjust the amount of users converted in one run.

Comment: Ok,thanks so much!! how do I do this, currently all my usernames are stored with the following code:
    username = db.StringProperty(required = True)

Comment: Hmm..currently the site isn't live so that's not a problem, is there anyway to initially set the username to lowercase when the user signs up?

Comment: sure, just use `user.username = name.lower()` everytime you create new user and save his/her user `name`

Comment: Ok did that and it worked, thanks.